# AndroidStudio: Setting an versionCode from mercurial in Gradle

Tags: android, mercurial, gradle, android-studio

I recently started using Android Studio after migrating from Eclipse. In Eclipse I had an ant snippet for getting the tip mercurial changeset number and placing it as the version code.

I wonder what's the best way to achieve this with Gradle. Is there a way to interface with the project's mercurial repository from gradle and do this without running a shell "hg" command?